# SQL Database Normalization Basics

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

If I am entering a multipart report into a database should I make each part a separate table?

The report may have additional parts added on to it as time goes on.

Is it bad practice to create a table that will have columns added to it as time goes on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Is it bad practice to create a table that will have columns added to it as time goes on?"

Nope. As long as it is one 'thing'.

Separate your data into the basic nouns, then work out the relationship types between them.

If it is one-to-many then put a foreign key on the many pointing to the one. If it is many-to-many then introduce a mapping table.

EDIT: To expand using the example given in the alternate answer...

An `Invoice` consists of `Description` `Date` `Notes` etc, so these should be fields on the invoice. However since it has **many** `InvoiceItems`, these should be a separate table with a foreign key in order to be easily expanded.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I make each part [of a report] a separate table?

Generally, no.

Reports are a "display" mechanism.  They don't have any structure in the database, generally speaking.  However, report structure *can* derive from database structure.

For example, consider an Invoice.  Generally, invoices (a type of report) will use at least two tables, each representing a "section" of the invoice:

```
InvoiceHeader
    Name
    Address ...etc

InvoiceLineItems
    ItemID
    Quantity ...etc
```

In addition, you can potentially have tables that represent sections of a report, but which are *not part of the actual data proper.*  However, it would be difficult to speculate about what those might look like without knowing more about your particular application.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the content of the report. What is the 'mulitpart' made up of?

For instance if I was to report on the staff in a given department I would expect one have one table containing all staff (or one set of tables if that normalisation made sense - but for this purpose lets imaging one table).  I might then have a report with multiple sections, one per staff member.

However if the report had a section on staff members, another on how many widgets they made and another on how many days they worked I would expect to have one table for staff, one for widgets and one for workdays.

Then my report would draw from the appropriate tables to populate the report.

Generally the rules of normalisation relate to the need to store the data effectively not to the design of a report.  The normalisation tries to avoid insert, deletion and update anomalies by ensuring each piece of data is held only once and is not affected by changes to other pieces of data.  This, more than a single report or any other single activity drives the normalisation.